# Using fread to read the contents of a file into a structure

Tags: c, linux, struct

In the "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment" book there's a part (ch 8.14, page 251) in which the author shows us the definition of the "acct" struct (used to store accounting records info).  He then shows a program in which he reads the accounting data from a file into the struct (the key part of which is):

```
fread (&acdata, sizeof(acdata), 1, fp)
```

The trouble I'm having is that I've heard that C compilers will sometimes rearrange the elements of a struct in memory in order to better utilize space (due to alignment issues).  So, if this code is just taking all of the content of the file and sticking it into acdata (and the contents of the file are arranged to match the ordering specified in the struct definition) if some of the elements of struct have been moved, then if I refer to them in code, I may not be getting what I expected (since the data in the file did not get rearranged the way the struct did in memory).

What am I missing (because from what I'm getting this doesn't seem reliable)?

Thanks for your help (my apologies if I've done something wrong procedurally - this is my first time posting)

Comment: it's not the rearranging of fields within a struct that you need to worry about, it's the alignment (and consequently padding) of them in a struct that you need to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes

**Your program will be stable.**

Your question has touched off a bonfire of portability recommendations that you didn't actually ask for. The question you seemed to be asking is *"is this code pattern and my program stable?".*  And the answer to that is ***yes.***

You structure will not be reordered. C99 specifically prohibits rearranging the structure members.<sup>1</sup>

Also, the layout and alignment do not depend on optimization level. If they did, all programs would have to be entirely built with the same optimization level, as well as all library routines, the kernel, all kernel interfaces, etc.

Users would also have to track, forever, the optimization level of every one of those interfaces listed above that ever had been compiled as part of the system.

The memory alignment rules are really a kind of [hidden **ABI**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). They can't change without adding very specialized and by definition rarely-used compiler flags. They tend to work just fine over different compilers. (Otherwise, every element of a system identified above would ALSO have to be compiled by the same compiler, or be useless. *Every compiler that supports a given system uses the exact same alignment rules.* Nothing would work, otherwise.) The compiler flags that change alignment policies are usually intended to be built into the compiler configuration for a given OS.

Now, your binary file layout, while perfectly reasonable, *is* a bit old-school. It has certain drawbacks. While none of these are show-stoppers and none are generally worth rewriting an app, they include:

- it's hard to debug binary files
- they do lock in a single byte order and a single alignment policy. In the (sadly, increasingly unlikely) case where you need to port to a new architecture, you might end up needing to unpack the record with memcpy(3). Not the end of the world.
- they aren't structured. Things like YAML and, ahem, even XML are sort of self-parsing, so it becomes a lot easier to read in a file, and certain types of file manipulations can be done with tools. Even more important, the file format itself becomes more flexible. Your ability to take advantage of the auto-parsed-object is limited, however, in C and C++.

As I understand Paxdiablo's request, he would like me to agree that there exist compiler options and pragmas that, if used, will alter the alignment rules. That's true. Obviously these options are used only for specific reasons.

---

<sup>1. **C99 6.7.2.1(13)** *Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields
reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared.*</sup>

Comment: Order is not allowed to change but padding/alignment can vary wildly depending on compiler options .

Comment: Not true. As I have explained, that would make those options completely useless on a given system. Yes, they are occasionally there, intended for compiler implementors and embedded system developers. No sane user is supposed to touch them, and they usually aren't exposed to the compiler front end.

Comment: Actually, they are _invaluable_ for reading foreign data formats and they are exposed quite readily. I don't intend to discuss further, I'll be happy to reverse the downvote if the answer is corrected.

Comment: @paxdiablo: DigitalRoss didn't claim (or currently does not) that options do not change alignment. He is claiming that optimization level does not affect alignment. On compilers I am aware of this is correct.

Comment: "Your program will be stable" **if** the files are written/read under exactly the same ABI in all cases. Otherwise, all bets are off. So, I think this answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 8):

## Worry!

You are right to worry about this issue and pay attention to it. It's a vexing problem, and often happens when you carry your source to another machine, with a different -- even slightly different -- architecture, and perhaps with a different OS or maybe a different compiler; compile your program there; and expect your structs to remain intact over `fwrite( )` and `fread( )`. Or when you add a 1-byte variable to your struct, recompile, and send out binaries to all your friends. Your program doesn't work on their machines anymore, for some mysterious reason.

Sometimes it works (by accident) and you never notice the problem; sometimes it doesn't work and you pull your hair out for a few days.

The isssue has nothing to do with rearrangement of struct members. Compilers don't do that. It has nothing to do with optimization, either.

The issue is ***byte alignment***, and the Wikipedia article mentioned below tells you how to fix up your structs so they'll always be correctly aligned. It's ***always a good idea*** to pay attention to byte alignment. Otherwise your program isn't portable. And, worse, the program you carefully compiled on your whiz-bang x86-64 and distributed to all of your customers all of a sudden won't run on their 32-bit machines.

Just as important: be mindful of the lengths and alignments of the struct members, too.

There's a nice [**Wikipedia article**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)  that explains the details. It's a very worthwhile read.

I would be wary of a compiler-specific pragma that does the job, but just for that compiler. If you put a pragma in your code, then your program isn't C anymore.

Comment: I was going to explain my downvote, but you fixed your answer so I've removed it. Thank you for noting that struct alignment is not going to change.  Remember, the OP gets to ask the question. While you or I would probably not write a program today that used raw binary output (yes, it's old-school with the obvious problems we both mentioned) *the question* was whether the program was safe from itself, and in fact it is. You answered a question about portability that the OP did not ask.

Comment: **A program compiled for x86-64 will never run on a 32-bit system.** A program built on a 32-bit system *will* run on a 64-bit one and it will use the same libraries and ABI (and therefore must use the same alignment rules) on both.  I doubt if it's "always a good idea" to use local ("pragma") compiler extensions. There are ways to achieve portability while also achieving C99-conforming language use.

Comment: @DigitalRoss -- Thank you for your courtesy in taking the trouble to explain your downvote! I appreciate it very much. As for giving an answer to a question that the OP didn't ask, well, I guess we can differ on what is or is not an appropriate answer. I think it's good to mention things that the OP perhaps hasn't considered. A discursive answer has saved my ass many and many a time. In this case, I've once been bitten hard, deep, and long by the struct-portability issue -- a painful memory -- and that must have motivated me.

Comment: @DigitalRoss -- I didn't say ***for*** an x86-64; I said ***on*** an x86-64. It's easy for a developer to forget or overlook or make a mistake about the target.

Comment: @DigitalRoss -- But of course you are right about pragma. I'll change that right now.

Comment: Thank you for bringing up the portability issue - if I had enough rep I would have upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 3):

The layout (padding and alignment, but not order) of the structure may change if you compile your code on a different compiler, or a later version of the compiler, or even with different compile-time options.

It *won't* change from run to run of the same compiled program - that would be a nightmare scenario :-)

So, provided the same program (or technically, *any* program which has the same structure layout encoded into it at compile time) is the one doing the reading, this will work just fine.

The relevant sections of the C99 standard are:

> 6.2.6.1/1: The representations of all types are unspecified except as stated in this subclause.
>
> 6.2.6.1/6 (the only mention of structures in that subclause): When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type, including in a member object, the bytes of the object representation that correspond to any padding bytes take unspecified values. The value of a structure or union object is never a trap  representation, even though the value of a member of the structure or union object may be a trap representation.

That's the only mention of structure padding in that subclause. In other words, it's up to the implementation and they don't even need to document it (unspecified as opposed to implementation-defined, which *would* require documenting).

> 6.7.2.1/13: ... There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.
>
> 6.7.2.1/15: There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.

---

If you were to create version 1.1 of your program and it uses a different structure layout (new compiler, different compiler options, `#pragma pack`, etc), it would very quickly be evident that you had a problem during your unit tests (which should include loading in a file from the previous version).

In that case, you could include some 'intelligence' in your 1.1 program which could recognise an earlier file layout and transform the data as it comes in. That's why good file formats will often have a version indicator (for the file layout version, not the program version) as the first item in that file.

For example, quite a few of my applications use an application identifier along with a 16-bit integer at the front of the file to indicate what application and version it is and the file loader part of the program can handle at least the current and previous versions (and often every version ever created).

The program version and file layout version are separate things - they can drift if, for example, you release ten versions of your program without needing to update the file layout.

Comment: If you'd care to leave a reason for the downvote, I could modify the answer or, more likely, tell you why you're wrong :-)

Comment: Ok.  Your first sentence made **3** errors. Layout does not change with different compilers on the same system, it can't, as I have explained. later versions cannot change the layout. (Unless that compiler is suddenly to be completely useless on any previously compiled kernel or library.) Different compiler options will not change the hidden alignment ABI. (Yes, there are occasionally some that do, but they are not intended for users, they are for the compiler or embedded system implementors, and it's obvious that they would entirely break system and library ABI's if used. We can ignore them.)

Comment: @DigitalRoss, the layout can and does change, depending on the compiler (and/or options) you use. Just picking some at random from gcc turns up `short-enums`, `short-double` and `pack_struct`.

Comment: And I didn't downvote in a childish fit (since I didn't even know you were the downvoter here when I did it). I downvoted an incorrect answer as per the policy. We just seem to disagree on what incorrect means.

Comment: Let's try to concentrate on the OP's actual question. He didn't ask *"Can I kill my program with an oddball compiler option",* he was wondering if the compiler would rearrange his struct and if his fread(3) use was stable. I'm sure you will agree that, if he doesn't *deliberately* change some fringe packing rules, his struct will have the same layout forever. It *absolutely has to* or all the kernel and library interfaces would break. Please tell me how that could happen, and I don't mean *"by the user shooting himself in the foot by deliberately changing the alignment".*

Comment: "No discussion" means "no discussion" - we've both made our arguments, the SO swarm can decide.

Answer (score 2):

The struct is written to the file based on how it is in memory. The ordering will be the same. Mixing compilers between write and read might be an issue however.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Not sure I follow.  If the file had a string on one line and a number on the next (and the struct was declared so that the string was the first element and the number the 2nd) and the struct was laid out in memory so that the int came first, then when fread loads the file into my struct and I try to access the string, won't that end up reading the int?  I'm not sure how the compiler could be aware of the link between my struct and a file.

Comment: If you write the bytes the compiler used to represent the whole struct, you would not be as aware of the ordering. It wouldn't be in your code. ....as other posters have noted, you could become aware of the ordering when you use different compiled code on the read and write sides because they may do things differently.

Assuming a typedef DATA of your struct (my C is rusty)....
DATA *dataPtr = malloc (sizeof(DATA));
dataPtr->i = 3;
dataPtr->s = malloc (4 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(dataPtr->s, "foo");